# PHP mysqli_num_rows always returns 0 even with data in database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have several database tables. All of them are full of data. I have the following PHP code that tries to retrieve the data:

```
$sql = "select inspection_date, inspection_type, capacity, criticality, man_hours from $table_name where device_number = '$device_number' order by inspection_date";

//printf("sql = $sql <br/>");

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $final_array[] = array("device_number"=>$all_ld_formatted[$i]['device_number'], "old_device_number"=>$all_ld_formatted[$i]['old_device_number'], 
            "type"=>$all_ld_formatted[$i]['type'], "building"=>$all_ld_formatted[$i]['building'], "room"=>$all_ld_formatted[$i]['room'], 
            "power"=>$all_ld_formatted[$i]['power'], "inspection_date"=>$row['inspection_date'], "inspection_type"=>$row['inspection_type'], 
            "capacity"=>$row['capacity'], "criticality"=>$row['criticality'], "man_hours"=>$row['man_hours']);
    }
} else {
    printf("no results <p/>");
}
```

The code above is running in a for-loop. So, that's why you see the $all_ld_formatted[$i]['value'] stuff in there. For some reason, the code always returns "no results". However, if I uncomment the printf("sql = $sql"); line, and copy and paste the query into PHPMyAdmin, I always get the results I'm looking for. Please help and thank you!

Regards,

Chris Martino

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: uhhh, whats `$table_name`? Does `$table_name` have any rows wherein `device_number=$device_number`? Is your `$conn` valid? Some other thing?

Comment: I really hope you're not storing different customer data in different tables. That's how you create an unmaintainable monstrosity.

Comment: Like chiliNUT asked, why is table name a variable? Have you created different tables for each of your parts?

Comment: If you're calling this in a loop, you might get rows for some iterations and zero rows for others. You should only print `no results` if *all* of the iterations return no results.

Comment: $conn is valid. I successfully connect earlier in my script, and run several successful queries in between the connection and the problem code.

Comment: This script is just local for now, not worried about SQL injection. This script is just for me.

Comment: The table name is a variable because the devices being stored required all sorts of different inspection types. The table name is a reference to the type of inspection that is required for a particular device.

Comment: This is being called in a loop because I need to get the same information for all 266 devices.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was closing the connection to the database before the query fired off. Sorry for wasting everyone's time!

Chris